# ESXi 4.0 install not reading drives through SATA controller card

Tags: linux, raid, vmware-esxi

installing ESXi 4.0 on a Dell PowerEdge SC1420 w/ a Syba SATA PCI-X 4x card.  installs fine w/out controller card, but i added 2 more drives.  getting error, not reading any drives.  tried different RAID configs and no RAID at all, same thing.  is there a way to load the drivers for the controller card on install kinda like w/ nLite/Windows?  i'd imagine this is the issue.  thx..

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to use supported hardware and can't load extra drivers.

See http://www.vm-help.com/esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php for a fairly comprehensive list of "whitebox" components, or alternatively search the [VMWare Compatibility Guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?rlz=1C1_____enAU352AU352&q=esxi%20hardware&aq=f&aqi=g-s3g2g-s2g1g-s1g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).